# Framer Asymmetrical Grid Fill

Tags: css-grid, framerjs

Does anyone know how to correct Framer's asymmetrical grid alignment when using frames to fill width? If I use multiples of 1fr to fill the grid, everything aligns. If I set asymmetrical values (say, 1:3), the columns don't align.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFDxE.png)

I'm new to CSS and Framer, so I'm hoping this is a rookie thing and an easy fix. Thanks in advance.